# similar function in php for selectall_hashref in perl?

Tags: php, perl

If i want an array in which index is first column of table , Then in perl i can write like this :

```
my $qStrN = "select * from table";
my $ref = $db->selectall_hashref($qStrN,'column_name') ; //column_name is the first column in table.
```

Then the result will be :

```
$var1 = {
'id'=>{'column_name'=>'id','type'=>'integer'} ,
'name'=>{'column_name'=>'name','type'=>'text'}
}
```

But in php if i write

```
$ref = pg_query($db=>db,$qStrN);
pg_fetch_all($ref);
```

Result will be :

```
Array(
[0]=>Array('column_name'=>'id','type'=>'integer'),
[1]=>Array('column_name'=>'name','type'=>'integer'))
```

How to change the index 0,1 etc. by first column_name of table in php ?? Any help??

Comment: if you use PDO in php the key will be the column name.

Comment: $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, "column_name"); like this??

Comment: `$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: not working it is not giving any log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer like this :

```
$qStrN = "select * from table";
$ref = pg_query($dbh->dbh,$qStrN);
$columns = pg_fetch_all($ref);
foreach($columns as $key=>$val) {
  $newKey = $val['column_name'];
  $columns[$newKey]=$val;
  unset($columns[$key]);
}
```

Now it is giving result same as selectall_hashref in perl.